# How can I add 2 stripes to WordPress menu bar?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am designing a web page and I am wondering how I can add two stripes to the menu bar, above the logo, with a space between the two stripes.

I am trying to make the first stripe thicker than the second one.

I am using Divi + CSS for this.

I have attached a picture to show how I am trying to make the menu bar look.

[image: Menu]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
header{border-top:10px solid grey; position:relative;}
header:after{content:''; position:absolute; left:0; top:15px; width:100%; height:5px; background:grey;}
```

I hope you are looking for something like this.

Comment: Thank you, how can I do this without using a top border? For example if I wanted to move the top stripe down a bit.